# Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting Giving Error

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, unit-testing

While using:

```
     using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting
```

It's giving me an reference error under .VisualStudio. Is this a NuGet Package I need or something. I read that I can go in and get the dll but where would I put the dll in my project. What folder would I add it to?

```
     Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.UnitTestFramework.dll
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to add a [reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wkze6zky%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) to the dll.

> In Solution Explorer, double-click the My Project node for the project.
>
> In the Project Designer, click the References tab.
>
> Click the Add button to open the Add Reference dialog box.
>
> In the Add Reference dialog box, select "Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.UnitTestFramework", then click OK.