# using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting compile error

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I'm trying to build this Visual Studio C# Solution : [TreeViewAdv](https://sourceforge.net/projects/treeviewadv/?source=typ_redirect)

I get compile errors like this:

> Using Directive is unnecessary The type or namespace name
>   'VisualStudio' could not be found (are you missing a using directive
>   or an assembly reference?)

on the line:

```
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;
```

So I remove that line I get this error:

> Error CS0246  The type or namespace name 'TestClass' could not be found
>   (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9730929/microsoft-visualstudio-testtools-unittesting-giving-error) says to add a reference, but I don't see the reference it refers to.

What gives?

Code example:

```
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;
using System;
using System.Text;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Aga.Controls.Tree;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
namespace Aga.Controls.UnitTests
{
    /// <summary>
    ///This is a test class for Aga.Controls.Tree.TreeNodeAdv and is intended
    ///to contain all Aga.Controls.Tree.TreeNodeAdv Unit Tests
    ///</summary>
    [TestClass()]
    public class TreeNodeAdvTest
    {
        private TestContext testContextInstance;
```

Edit:
In response to the "duplicate" flag:
The directory `C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE` does not have a `Public Assemblies` folder. Also I don't have a `C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 15.0`, which I can't say that I understand. Maybe 15 is using the 12 directories?

Comment: Thanks for pointing out that "duplicate" question. That doesn't work in this case, unfortunately. See adding info to question.

Comment: Have you figured it out? I try to build TreeViewAdv. VS2015 updates some solution and project files firstly. The reference Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting in project Aga.Control.Unit.Tests shows warning, so I remove it. Finally, follow the steps in the "duplicate" question. And now, VS2015 builds and tests TreeViewAdv.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Visual Studio 2013 I do the following steps to build the project:

1. Remove the reference Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting from the project Aga.Control.Unit.Tests
2. Add the same reference but from this directory C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\PublicAssemblies.